# Why tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory isn't returning the full path (with the selected dirname)?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.5

I'm trying to get the full path of a directory selected via tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory, but it only returns the path of the root folder, for example, selection the folder /root will return only '/', this seems strange, how to get it return the full path in python3.5?

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
dirname = filedialog.askdirectory(parent=root,initialdir="/",title='Please select a directory')
if len(dirname ) > 0:
    print("You chose %s" % dirname)
```

Comment: it works as expected on my mac, what OS are you using?

Comment: Linux gnu 4.2.0-27-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 22 04:49:08 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: so it is returning the folder open instead of the one selected? if you double click on `/root` to navigate to it then  confirm does it give you the correct path? I remember my friend having the same issue with linux on programs other then python.

Comment: That was the problem, WE have to double-click then press ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`filedialog.askdirectory()`](https://fossies.org/dox/Python-3.5.1/filedialog_8py_source.html#l00426) method returns an instance of [`filedialog.Directory`](https://fossies.org/dox/Python-3.5.1/filedialog_8py_source.html#l00351) class that need a [PyObject](https://fossies.org/dox/Python-3.5.1/structPyObject.html) command:

[image]

The mere selection of a folder does not represent a command, thus you do not get printed the folder you want. By double clicking on the folder you want represents a satisfying and coherent PyObject command resulting in the result you expect.

In simple words: **you need to double click** on the folder you want to open, then click Ok and **not simply select it** and click on `Ok` on the file open dialog window. Otherwise, you will get printed the path of the directory where you are now (`initialdir = '/'`)

Comment: on python 3 askdirectory() returns type str class object