# How to save askdirectory result in a variable I can use using tkinter with OOP?

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I have ran into some trouble.
I'm quite new to OOP and working with `tkinter` and GUI's in general.

I have managed to find some code on the Internet and meshed it all together to create something and I'm nearly where I want to be.

So what I want is some help figuring this out.

How can I assign results of `askdirectory` to a variable I can use elsewhere?

```
# coding=utf-8
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font as tkfont
from tkinter import filedialog


class MainApp(tk.Tk):
    ....
class SelectFunction(tk.Frame):
    ....
class FunctionChangeName(tk.Frame):
    ....
        a = Gui(self)
        # this gets me the askdirectory but how to add it to a variable?
```

Above is the call to run `askdirectory` code, and it works, just need to find out how to save it to a variable so I can use it, I have tried to print it in several ways, but all I get is something along the lines `.!frame.!functionchangename.!gui`.

```
class SelectDir:
    def __init__(self, container, title, initial):
        self.master = container

        self.initial = initial
        self.selected = initial

        self.options = {'parent': container,'title': title,'initialdir':initial,}

    def show(self):
        result = filedialog.askdirectory()
        if result:
            self.selected = result

    def get(self):
        return self.selected


class Gui(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, container):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, container)

        frame = tk.Frame(container)
        frame.pack()

        self.seldir = SelectDir(self, "Select directory", "D:\\MyPgm\\Python\\Tiles_8")

        button = tk.Button(frame, text="Select directory", command=self.select_dir)
        button.grid(column=0, row=0)

        self.act_dir = tk.StringVar()
        self.act_dir.set("D:\\MyPgm\\Python\\Tiles_8")

        entry = tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=self.act_dir, width=30)
        entry.grid(column=0, row=1)

    def select_dir(self):
        self.seldir.show()
        self.act_dir.set(self.seldir.get())
        # or
        # result = seldir.show()
        # self.act_dir.set(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you looked at the question [Why tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory isn't returning the full path (with the selected dirname)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105688/why-tkinter-filedialog-askdirectory-isnt-returning-the-full-path-with-the-sele)

Comment: I have read it now, doesnt unfortunately help in my case. The selected dir gets outputted inside the **Gui class**, but i cant access it from other classes. I can execute the code from other classes with  **a = Gui(self)** like i did inside **FunctionChangeName class** but i need to be able to save the actual string path to a variable that i can use else where, thats what i cannot do and need help with.

Comment: Like i have now **a = Gui(self)** it calls the Classes and print the button and open directory browser and lets me select a directory then and it then outputs it to the screen, but if i do b = a, print(a) inside **class FunctionChangeName** all i get is = **.!frame.!functionchangename.!gui** so i need a way to print **b** as an actual path i.e /home/user/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save "self" return value to a variable from Class B: to Class A when Class B gets that value returned by Class C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50964709/how-to-save-self-return-value-to-a-variable-from-class-b-to-class-a-when-clas)

Comment: Right after the `self.seldir.show()` in the `select_dir()` function, you should be able to access `self.seldir.selected`. Without an MCVE (see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's hard to understand and help with your question.

Answer (score 0):

## I had an idea:

example, if you have f inside a function, you can make it global to have access as variable

```
def print_path():  
    # select working directory
    global f #make f global to access the path
    f = filedialog.askdirectory(parent=root, initialdir="/", title='Select Dir')
```