# How to save "self" return value to a variable from Class B: to Class A when Class B gets that value returned by Class C

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

first of all im pretty new to OOP coding, so sorry for asking stupid questions.

I have a problem returning a value from **Class AskDir** that gets its value from **Class SelectDir** to **Class MainWindow** if that makes sense

Currently the code i have works, in every other way, except I cannot save the actual "self" (which is the path i.e. "/home/etc/") return value from **Class AskDir()** to another variable no matter what i do.

From what i have read i should be able to get the return value with **a = AskDir(self)
print(a)**, but what I get instead is **".!frame.!functionchangename.!askdir"**

So in short, how to save actual return path from a function inside Class AskDir, to be saved to variable a in Class MainWindow()?

To clarify, what i want is for Class MainWindow() to have a variable (a) that gets the return value from a subfunction get() inside Class SelectDir(), and that value should be the **path** that get() function returns

simplified code:

```
class MainWindow:
    self.controller = controller

    # prints the button to this frame!
    getdir = AskDir(self)
    print(getdir) # this should return actual path (/home/etc/), but it doesnt

class AskDir(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, container)

        self.selectdir = SelectDir(self, "Select directory", 
                                   "/home/user/folder/")

        button = tk.Button(frame, text="Select directory",
                           command=self.select_dir)

        self.act_dir = tk.StringVar()
        self.act_dir.set("/home/")

    def select_dir(self):
        self.selectdir.show()
        self.act_dir.set(self.selectdir.get())

class SelectDir:
    def __init__(self, container, title, initial):
        self.master = container

    def show(self):
        result = filedialog.askdirectory()
        if result:
            self.selected = result

    # THIS RETURNS THE ACTUAL PATH!
    def get(self):
        return self.selected
```

Comment: the self is working in the class but not between a class and another; if you want pass a value from a class to another you need call the class  and return some value.

Comment: Can you try posting a simple(r) example where you explain exactly what you want to do. It's very confusing from your question to understand what specifically it is you want to do, especially when you refer to classes that don't exist in your code.

Comment: Ok, give me a second, ill edit code a bit.

Comment: You are confusing functions and classes.  `getdir = AskDir(self)` will create an instance of the AskDir class and retain the reference to it in the getdir variable. You should create an instance of the class then call one of its methods which will return the file path. For example `directoryClass = AskDir(self)` `getdir = directoryClass.get()`

Comment: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and don't repost questions that you have already asked but got no answers to. Also `**` is **not** the way to markup `code`, use `\`` (backtick) characters. If you're going to ask others for help here, I suggest you take a little time learn how to use the site properly.

Comment: sorry forpossible repost, i was specificly told yesterday to not do heavy edits on posts and just ask a new questions instead. Guess i should have deleted the old post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

I can see no need to have SelectDir as a class given that its purpose is just to call the `askdirectory` method and return the selected folder path so I've change it to a function.

With this example, pressing the "Select directory" button will open the directory dialog and then place the selected directory text in to an Entry widget.

If the `MainWindow` class wishes to do anything with the path once it has been set then you just need to call the `get_dir` method of `AskDir` e.g. `print(askDir.get_dir()`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

def doStuffFunction(value):
    print(value)

class MainWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None,**kw):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master=master,**kw)
        self.askDir = AskDir(self)
        self.askDir.grid()
        doStuffButton = tk.Button(self, text="Do Stuff", command=self.doStuff)
        doStuffButton.grid()


    def doStuff(self):
        doStuffFunction(self.askDir.get_dir())

class AskDir(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master=master,**kw)



        button = tk.Button(self, text="Select directory",
                           command=self.select_dir)
        button.grid(row=0,column=1)

        self.act_dir = tk.StringVar()
        self.act_dir.set("/home/")

        self.pathBox = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.act_dir,width=50)
        self.pathBox.grid(row=0,column=0)

    def select_dir(self):
        selectdir = SelectDir("Select directory", "/home/user/folder/")
        self.act_dir.set(selectdir)

    def get_dir(self):
        return self.act_dir.get()


def SelectDir(title,initial):
    result = filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir=initial,title=title)
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    MainWindow(root).grid()
    root.mainloop()
```

You can now use the `AskDir` class as many times as you want in the MainWindow (perhaps to select Source and Destination paths). This has been added to my example with the `doStuff` method inside `MainWindow`.

Comment: It is almost working, its printing a path now, like i wanted, but it is printing the **self.act_dir.set path** always, which is **/home/**, might be a mistake on my part, implementing the given code to mine, ill try and see if i can fix it.

Comment: Probably a timing thing. You're probably calling print before the user has had a chance to select a new directory and self.act_dir is updated.

Comment: No, i still cannot get it to work, tried for hours now :( Say we use the code you provided as an example and we add a function `def savepaths(self)` inside the `class MainWindow()` and we wanted to pass the paths `save_dir` and `read_dir` into variables there, from `MainWindow`, how would that happen? I need these paths so i can pass them to another pythonfile, that uses them to do stuff.

Comment: @Nanoni I've updated my example to show how the folder path can be used to as an argument that is passed to another function `doStuffFunction`. I've added a button that the user can click when they are happy with their folder selection and want the "stuff" to happen.

Comment: Oh... now i see where my mistake was. I had the call `save_dir = AskDir(self).pack()` for askDir class inside MainWindow class and i also tried to call `save_dir` variable from `class MainWindow` inside to `doStuff()` function